# How to render igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

There is dataset with code below. And I need get a graph like in the picture, without changing frame. I tried use `rbind` to add more hierarchy to data frame in favor to get diagram like  in picture. `col0` and `col1` data is changing debending on data while `col2` remains always the same.

```
df <- data.frame(col0 = c("Cat Dog Wolf", "Cat Dog Wolf", "Cat Dog Wolf"),
col1 = c( "Cat", "Dog", "Wolf"),
col2 = c( "Feline", "Canis", "Canis2"))

df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0="Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Canis2", col2 = "Canis"))

df <-df[c('col1', 'col2')]
names(df) <-c('from', 'to')
abc <-union(df$to, df$from)
g <-graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = abc)
plot(g, vertex.size = 20, vertex.label.dist = 0.5, vertex.color = "blue",
edge.arrow.size = 0.5, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three edges taken from only two columns ("From" and "To"). But you have three columns in `df` so you have to choose from them. I created a new column with the names from `col1` and `col2` pasted together. Then, I chose the first two vertex from the top and `rbind` the third one.

```
df <- data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf",
col1 = c( "Cat", "Dog", "Wolf"),
col2 = c( "Feline", "Canis", "Canis2"))
df$col1_2 <- paste(df$col2,df$col1)

df <-  rbind(df[1:2,c(1,4)],data.frame(col0=df[2,4],col1_2=df[3,4]))

names(df) <-c('from', 'to')
abc <-union(df$to, df$from)
g <-graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = abc)
plot(g, vertex.size = 20, vertex.label.dist = 0.5, vertex.color = c("lightblue","red","green","white"),
edge.arrow.size = 0.5, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g))
```

[image]

Comment: @DeividasKiznis I updated my answer. To get the colors, you need this: `vertex.color = c("lightblue","red","green","white")`